# Change directory to directory of argument

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I have a script that accepts a path to file as its only argument. For example the input can be `D:\Folder_A\Folder_B\filename.txt`.

How do I change directory to the one of this file given that I am not guaranteed that the file and script reside on the same drive?

I know that `cd /d` can change drive as well as directory. However something like `cd /d %1` results in `The directory name is invalid.` because `%1` is not path to a folder but path to a file.

Comment: `cd /D "%~dp1"` or `pushd "%~dp1"` with a `popd` before leaving batch file. Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `call /?` and `cd /?` and `pushd /?` and `popd /?` and read each output help carefully.

Comment: In addition to the help from `/?`, you can also look at SS64 on [`cd` or `chdir`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html), [`call`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html), [`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html), and [`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a block of code which checks the input, and provides a message to the end user, should it not be an existing file path, *(absolute, relative to the current directory)*.

For example:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
For %%G In ("%~1") Do If "%%~aG" Lss "-" (Echo Error! Invalid file argument.
    "%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe" /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL & GoTo :EOF
    ) Else If "%%~aG" GEq "d" (Echo Error! file expected but folder provided.
        "%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe" /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL & GoTo :EOF
    ) Else CD /D "%~dp1"
Echo "%CD%" & Pause
```

*The last line was added just to provide you with an indication of the current directory change. You would obviously replace that with the rest of your script.*

*Please note the information provided in the comments too. You could for instance, replace `CD /D "%~dp1"`, with `PushD "%~dp1"`, you could alternatively use the `for` variable modifier `%%~dpG` instead of `%~dp1`.*